# Fact Table Design Suggestions

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-modeling, data-warehouse

To make things simple I have a transactional system which logs instant messages between a doctor and patient. At the end each session between the doctor and patient the doctor fills out an outcome form which is stored in a DimOutcome table which looks like this:

```
DimOutcome
----------
PK_OutcomeKey
OutcomeCategory1
OutcomeCategory2
OutcomeCategory3
...
```

I'm looking for the best way to design the fact table which will track messages. One thing that needs to be taken into consideration is that sometimes chat sessions can go unanswered (i.e. out of hours contact) and then can be followed up.

What would be the ideal way to design a FactMessage, taking into consideration that I need to track the DimOutcome with each chat session.

I'm thinking I will need to create one fact for messages and another for the overall session, would this be the only way? I would also like to track the amount of time between each message and the total session?

Comment: you have posted this with data-warehouse tag. What's your warehousing usecase? What kinds of "read" (reports in warehousing jargon) operations be expected on this data you collect? How much data are we talking abt? MBs, GBs, TBs, 10s of TBs, more... ?

Answer (score 2):

> the fact table which will track messages

First, be aware that in a fact table there is usually data, that can be aggregated, measured facts. Dimensions are used to filter the data in the fact table. Everything else doesn't make much sense in data warehousing. Maybe a normalized database model would be better for your needs.

> One thing that needs to be taken into consideration is that sometimes
>   chat sessions can go unanswered

That for example would be in a dimension i.e. DimSession, holding attributes of all sessions like the status, i.e. unanswered. Note that other attributes of the session, like the participants, might be in dimensions DimDoctor and DimPatient.

You also said, that you want to track the "DimOutcome". Here are two possibilities. First, you save this information in the dimension "session". So you can filter your fact table for the different outcomes.
The other possibility would be that you have columns for each outcome in your fact table. So that you have the amount of sessions per outcome. That would at least be something measurable. 
What you have to consider here is the granularity of your fact table. Has it one entry per session or per day? One entry per session isn't maybe the best choice if you go with having outcome columns in your fact table, since you could also have this information by filtering per DimSession and doing a COUNT(*) on your fact table.

> I'm thinking I will need to create one fact for messages and another
>   for the overall session, would this be the only way?

I think this whole data-warehousing thing isn't what you are looking for. A normalized data structure would be better for your needs.

If you want to know more about it, google for star schema or snowflake schema if you want to get an idea, how data-warehousing is usually realized.

A very shortened star schema...

[image: A very shortened star schema structure]